# Find the image of (1,1,1) by T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Question: Find the image of (1,1,1) by T**

$$T(x,y,z) = (y,6y,x+y+z)$$

I found the **standard matrix** to be:

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&6&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}

I'm confused on how to approach this question.

- In order to find the image is it possible to inverse the values of it's standard matrix?
- Would I able to use the identity matrix of 3 and inverse the values of that to find the image?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Image of an input is the value taken by the function at that input. e.g. if $f(x)=x+2$, then the image of $x=3$ is $f(3)=3+2=5$. So just apply the definition. It is much simpler than what you are making it to be.

Comment: Upper right matrix entry should be $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a lot easier than you seem to think this is.

We just insert $x = 1, y = 1, z = 1$ in the given expression for $T$ and get
$$
T(1,1, 1) = (1, 6\cdot 1 ,1+ 1 + 1) = (1, 6, 3)
$$

Comment: This seems to easy... isn't the image supposed to be an actual reflection? or maybe I'm just unsure on my definitions.

Comment: @MathNoob No, when we talk about functions, "image" is more or less synonymous with "value".

Answer (score 1):

Since $T(x,y,z) = (y,6y,x+z)$, $T(1,1,1)=(1,6,3)$. You don't need the matrix.